# jQuery event triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

I have cloned divs containing buttons that clone their parents. Upon trying to click the buttons, events are triggered `2n` times such that clicking the second clone produces 4 other clones and so on:

```js
$(".add").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(".cloneable").clone(true).appendTo(".container");
});

$(".rem").off("click").on("click", function() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].childElementCount > 1) {
    $(".cloneable:last").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cloneable">
    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary add" role="button">Add cell</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary rem" role="button">Remove cell</a>
    </div>
    <iframe src="index.php"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: container is not defined"`

Comment: Should be working fine now @LeeTaylor

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things.

1. It's easier to use a deferred click handler.
2. You were cloning all 'cloneable', not just the `first`. jQuery will find all `cloneable` and clone them, not just your original.
3. Remove now removes the one you clicked on, not the last one.
4. The `disabled` class will be added/removed to the `rem` button, depending on if there is only one left or not.

```js
$(".container").on("click", ".add", function(e) 
{
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(".container .rem").removeClass("disabled");
  
  let $cloneable = $(".cloneable").first().clone(true);
  $cloneable.appendTo(".container");
  
}).on("click", ".rem", function() 
{
  if($(this).hasClass("disabled") ) return;
  
  $(this).closest(".cloneable").remove();
  
  if($(".container .rem").length === 1)
    $(".container .rem").addClass("disabled");  
});
```

```css
.btn.btn-primary
{
  background:#d5d5d5;padding:4px;cursor:pointer;
}

.btn.btn-primary.disabled
{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cloneable">
    <div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary add" role="button">Add cell</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary disabled rem" role="button">Remove cell</a>
    </div>
    <iframe src="trial37.php"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can only run .rem once. After that no cells are removed

Comment: Also, after the first .rem, .add is not working anymore

Comment: Looks ok now, just one suggestion maybe when there is one cell left disable the remove function. I mean, that's not in the question but I would do it just so you have an option to add more cells if needed.

Comment: @al1en Done. Please mark as answered.

Comment: @LeeTaylor are your methods chainable?

Comment: Define `chainable` in this context. I'm not extending jQuery here.

Comment: Can the two `$(".container")` be chained in this case?

Comment: Yes, see the edit.

Comment: @LeeTaylor, I upvoted your answer but it is not my question to mark it as amswered

Comment: @al1en Sorry, I got confused over who asked!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".add").on("click", function(e) {  $(this).parent(".cloneable").clone(true).appendTo(".container");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cloneable">
    <a class="btn btn-primary add" role="button">Add cell</a>
    <div>CONTENT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, what's happening in your method is that you are doing a new query each time you click and it returns all the `.clonable` elements and then clones them. What you want is to only find the one relevant to the item you clicked on, so you want to start with `$(this)` which is the item clicked and then you can use the `parent()` method to go up the DOM tree looking for the selector.

In these sorts of situations, it can help to put a `debugger;` inside your click event and then execute the method one at a time. Like `$('.clonable')`. You can then see maybe that it gets larger every time and that they point to all the existing elements.